# Employed but no tax returns. Can I apply for French Schengen Visa?

Tags: schengen, tourist-visas, schengen-visas

My tax papers are yet under computation with my chartered accountant for various reasons and hence I do not have tax returns for the visa documentation. Also, my employer does not provide with Form 16 [(wikipedia link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_tax_forms#About_Form_16) as well.

How should I apply for the visa?

I have fixed deposit receipts worth 600,000 Indian Rupees (approx. 8000 EUR) and already visited 10 countries previously including USA.

Comment: SInce you're discussing Schengen Visa, it's probably helpful to convert that 6 lacs into euro's.

Comment: What is an "IT return"?

Comment: @phoog Income Tax

Comment: What's Form 16?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It is a statement provided by employers to employees in India. It shows the salary paid in a financial year and the amount deducted as income tax "at source" by employers. In many cases, it is an acceptable alternative to Income tax return in India

Answer (score 2):

In the same situation in the US, when applying for German Shenghen visa for my mom as a sponsor, I provided the old tax return (for year 2014), a brief informal summary for year 2015 with a copy of the last 2015 paystub (in US it also lists the total income and tax payments), and a note that I haven't filed 2015 tax return yet. It was accepted, and the visa was issued.

If you don't have paystubs showing this information, you can provide either:

- all paystubs for the 2015 (showing you were receiving salary the whole year);
- bank statements, if your salary was deposited to your bank;
- a statement from your accountant summarizing your income for 2015, which should also mention the information where your accountant got those numbers;

If the Consulate needs more information, they would let you know during the interview, and you'd be able to follow up with them (even by email).